# How to display the result of a char variable in a Windows Form Based application using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

```
public void caesarcipher()
{
    char c, a;
    string PT = textBox1.Text;
    PT = PT.ToLower();
    for (int i = 0; i < PT.Length; i++)
    {
        c = Convert.ToChar(PT.Substring(i, 1));
        if ((int)c + 3 > 122) a = (char)(c + 3 - 26);
        else a = (char)(c + 3);
        label2.Text = a; //error here as label can not display char
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    caesarcipher();
}
```

That is my partial code, what I want is that to display all the elements stored in char a in a label and converting the char a to string displays only the last element which does not help.
I hope I am clear enough.

Comment: `a.ToString()`?

Comment: then it displays only the last element

Comment: `converting the char a to string displays only the last element` are you kidding? A character is only 1 "element"

Comment: If you want a collection of characters (multiple elements) you need a character array

Comment: @AbhiB - A character is literally one element only.

Comment: Perhaps you want `label2.Text += a.ToString()`

Comment: @gravity thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: @BradleyUffner That does work but I want to replace the original text value of the label,your code concats original text and result text

Comment: @AbhiB Clear the label before the loop.

Comment: @BradleyUffner How can I do that? I am sorry I am new at this.

Comment: @AbhiB `label2.Text = "";`

Comment: This line, `c = Convert.ToChar(PT.Substring(i, 1));` can be simplified to just `c = PT[i];`

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thank you for your help! also how can I "upvote" your answer?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @AbhiB You can normally update an answer with the controls to the left, but I didn't provide my answer as an actual answer.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time to fully detail the reasons why it works in a way that I think qualifies as a true answer on this site.  If anyone else wants to take what I wrote and provide an actual, true answer that you can upvote, they are welcome to do so.  If you think that you understand why it works, and can explain it in detail, you are even allowed to answer your own question, and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick thanks to @BradleyUffner and @ChrisDunaway

```
public void caesarcipher()
    {
        char c, a;
        string PT = textBox1.Text;
        PT = PT.ToLower();
        label2.Text = " "; //added this line
        for (int i = 0; i < PT.Length; i++)
        {
            c = PT[i]; //changed
            //c = Convert.ToChar(PT.Substring(i, 1));
            if ((int)c + 3 > 122) a = (char)(c + 3 - 26);
            else a = (char)(c + 3);
            label2.Text += a.ToString(); //changes here solved the error
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, `a` will ever only hold a single char since you defined it as `char a` and are setting it equal to a char.

For this, you would need to change the definitions to `char[] a = new char[PT.Length]`

Instead calling `a =`, you would then have to use the index to set the char at the location to what you want. Replacing `a =` with `a[i] =` would suffice.

To display the char array, `label2.Text = new string(a)` will do the trick.

```
public void caesarcipher()
{
    string PT = textBox1.Text;
    PT = PT.ToLower();
    char c;
    char[] a = new char[PT.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < PT.Length; i++)
    {
        c = Convert.ToChar(PT.Substring(i, 1));
        if ((int)c + 3 > 122) a[i] = (char)(c + 3 - 26);
        else a[i] = (char)(c + 3); 
    }
    label2.Text = new string(a);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    caesarcipher();
}
```

Comment: will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add each character to the `label2.Text` property instead of reassigning the property. You can also get rid of some of the explicit casting; `char` will get cast to an `int` implicitly when added to an `int:

```
public void CaesarCipher()
{
    label2.Text = "";

    foreach (var character in textBox1.Text.ToLower())
    {
        var intVal = character + 3;
        label2.Text += (char)(intVal > 122 ? intVal - 26 : intVal);
    }
}
```